# Adding mysql_real_escape_string() causes blank values to be stored to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

```
$submit=$_POST['submit'];
$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$phone=preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_POST['phone']);
$phone =  (int) $phone;
$adress=$_POST['city']  . ' ' .  $_POST['district'] . ' ' . $_POST['adress'];
$friends=$_POST['friends'];
$school=$_POST['school'];
$info=$_POST['info'];
$dob = $_POST['year']."-". $_POST['month']."-".$_POST['day'];
```

Recently i added to my page:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
$_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
```

i want to sanitize all $_POST's (http://prntscr.com/22uot) ID 20 before adding `mysql_real_escape_string()` to my page, id 22 after. My page puts all variables to db table's fields but when I want to add `mysql_real_escape_string()` to variable it puts nothing into the field. I dunno what to do.

Comment: Please provide the piece of code that you are using to insert data. Otherwise we dunno what to do.

Comment: The first thing you should do, if you're asking for help, is post your code. I assure you the function works, so it's a matter of figuring out what's going on in your particular case.

Comment: if the string doesn't need to be escaped, it won't be escaped. please explain what you want to acheive

Comment: i want to sanitize $_POST's. http://prntscr.com/22uot ID 20 before adding mysql_real_escape_string to my page, id 22 after

Comment: Can you show us how you're putting the data in the database as well? Also, could you remove mysql_real_escape_string(), and confirm everything works properly without it? This may be an unrelated error.

Comment: It's a bad idea to sanitize all $_POST fields with mysql_real_escape_string, because sometimes you don't want to insert them all to the database, but use them in a different way.

Comment: @Tural Teyyuboglu: There you go. See, how nice your question looks? +1 for the effort.

Comment: Hi, when I click on the link, it says "The screenshot was removed." Can you please replace it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As clearly indicated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (which is the first things you should browse, when in doubt):

> A MySQL connection is required before
>   using mysql_real_escape_string()
>   otherwise an error of level E_WARNING
>   is generated, and FALSE is returned.
>   If link_identifier isn't defined, the
>   last MySQL connection is used.

Be sure you've connect to your database before using this function.

```
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

Answer (score 3):

to use this function, you must have a connection opened to your database before, like :

```
mysql_connect(...);
$fullname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
etc ...
```