# Troubleshooting "Access denied" error when calling mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: mysql, pdo

How come I can't get `mysql_real_escape_string` to work when using PDO? I keep getting an error when using

```
try {
    include "connect_to_db.php";

    $sql = sprintf("NULL, '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string('Woot')
    );
    $count = $dbh->exec($sql);
    $dbh = null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The error always points to the line where mysql_real_escape_string is

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in D:\pathhere\file.php on line 44
```

I've even using the root user now for testing but it still won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384423/mysql-real-escape-string-doesnt-work

Comment: If you could insert the error message/code in here it would be easier to suggest solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most of mysql_* functions use a mysql connection resource. as the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) of the function mentions, it actually needs a mysql_connect() resource, which is not available in your code since you are using PDO.

However the solution is not using this function if you want to make sure your SQL is secure. You could use parameters in your SQL query, [create a prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), and then execute it. This solution uses PDO way of running queries, and is as secure.

**Update:**

If you just need a string to be escaped for a SQL using PDO, you could use the [quote() method of the PDO object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php). However it is not a common task to do so. Most of times when you want a string to be escaped for a SQL query, you actually want to run the query. If this is the case as the documentation itself suggest, you'd better use the [prepare() method of the PDO object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). You could read the example section of the [PDO prepared statements documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for more information.

Comment: So that's why. The change to PDO makes mysql_real_escape_string obsolete. Is there a PDO alternative to mysql_real_escape_string or something similar that others use?

Comment: @enchance: Just updated the answer explaining your question in the comment.